# parse data with event listener?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to parse data to a function from the event listener ?

I have this:

```
div.addEventListener('mousedown',run(id),false);

function run(e,id){
   console.log(id);
}
```

Thing is it executes straight away. The other problem is - if i want to parse the variable `id`, and the `run` function recieves `e` for the event, how do you parse any thing else =/ It's a bit confusing to work out what order `e` is (before or after your designated variables that you want to parse)

The current work around so far was to assign `id` to window so its basically a global... but i'm wondering if parsing via the event is possible at all ?

Comment: div.addEventListener( 'mousedown', run, false ); with run() you execute the function but you want to hand over a reference of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to create a new listener function in which the `id` variable is already bound to the value that you want, like this:

```
function newListener(id) {
    var listener = function(e) {
        console.log(id);
    }
    return listener;
}
div.addEventListener('mousedown',newListener(id),false);
```

`newListener(id)` defines a new function, in which the value that the `id` variable had at the time is available inside that function. Then the javascript environment will call *that* function when the mouse button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

An event handler does not take arguments directly, you are calling the function run(id), not passing a handler, here is how you pass it (using anonymous function)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener

```
div.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e){
  doSomething(id);
},false);

function doSomething(id){
  console.log(id);
}
```